# Console.log in production mode for nodejs

Tags: node.js, console

I am making the api in node.js and when i put my code into production then  console.log("hello") is not working. It is not showing even "hello" on terminal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("hello")` should display on all environment including your production.

basically, you should avoid using `console.log` and use other modules like `debug` instead. then you can turn on/off based on the environment easily using `DEBUG` env variable